# Confusion on MiniMax algorithm

Tags: algorithm, minimax

So i'm currently working on an assignment that revolves around the MiniMax algorithm on a game that is a combination of Mancala and NIM. The way the program works is to ask user for the current state of board and the program is suppose to spit out what the first move the user should take to win the game. I'm just confused on is am I suppose to generate the entire game tree with all the possible solutions and at the leaf nodes have the utility function first then have the MiniMax algorithm recursively run through it or does the tree get created within the MiniMax algorithm? I'm sorry if this question is very unclear but I'm just kind of stuck on this idea and I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: In practice: this tree is generated on-the-fly. There is one important reason: you won't use pure min-max, but some alpha-beta like pruning and therefore possibly not searching the entire tree (important: a good move-ordering). The second reason: you won't be able to search all states (infinite depth) in most games; so iterative-deepening is used to restrict the search to some fixed depth / plys (increased when time left)

Comment: The game-tree is not explicitly generated, but only a traversal of it is performed. Never during the minimax execution will you have the entire tree in memory. As mentioned by sascha, things are done on-the-fly, because at any node (any board configuration) you can easily generate its successor states. The key aspect here is that when you apply a move on a board configuration (thus obtaining another board configuration), you actually move within this conceptual game-tree.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to write a minimax function is to traverse the search tree by making and unmaking moves. You only ever store one game state at a time, and by making and unmaking moves on that game state you traverse the whole tree. If this is confusing then it will be helpful to look at some minimax psudocode. Note that there are two commonly used variants of minimax, regular minimax and negamax. The psudeocode is minimax because it is more intuituve but in practice I would recommend the negamax variant because it is much simpler:

```
int max(int depth){
    if(this state is terminal){//won, lost, drawn, or desired search depth is reached
        return value
    }
    //if the state is non terminal
    //we want to examine all child nodes. We do this by making all possible moves from this state, calling the min function 
    //(all childs of max nodes are min nodes) and then unmaking the moves. 
    int bestVal = -infinity;
    generate move list;
    for(all moves in move list){
        makeMove(this move in move list);
        int val = min(depth -1);
        unMakeMove(this move in move list);
        bestVal = max(val,bestVal);
    }
    return bestVal;
}

int min(int depth){
    if(this state is terminal){//won, lost, drawn, or desired search depth is reached
        return value
    }
    //if the state is non terminal
    //we want to examine all child nodes. We do this by making all possible moves from this state, calling the max function 
    //(all childs of min nodes are max nodes) and then unmaking the moves. 
    int bestVal = +infinity;
    generate move list;
    for(all moves in move list){
        makeMove(this move in move list);
        int val = min(depth -1);
        unMakeMove(this move in move list);
        bestVal = min(val,bestVal);
    }
    return bestVal;
}
```

Thus you traverse the entire tree by keeping track of one game state and recursively making and unmaking moves on that game state. Once you understand this look into alpha beta pruning. Also be aware that this function only returns the value of the best move not the move itself. You will want a special function that keeps track of the best move as well to call at the root.